# How to validate nested Form data in Vue Element?

Tags: vue.js

I need to validate nested form data in Vue Element. The [example](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#delete-or-add-form-items-dynamically) is pretty same with my code. The only difference that `dynamicValidateForm` is wrapped in `MainForm`. But I can't get it work.

https://jsfiddle.net/mwxaqhn7/

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">

    <el-form :model="MainForm.dynamicValidateForm" ref="MainForm.dynamicValidateForm" label-width="120px" class="demo-dynamic">

        <el-form-item
          v-for="(domain, index) in MainForm.dynamicValidateForm.domains"
          :label="'Domain' + index"
          :key="domain.key"
          :prop="'domains.' + index + '.value'"
          :rules="rules"
        >
          <el-input v-model="domain.value"></el-input><el-button @click.prevent="removeDomain(domain)">Delete</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item>
          <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('MainForm')">Submit</el-button>
          <el-button @click="addDomain">New domain</el-button>
          <el-button @click="resetForm('MainForm.dynamicValidateForm')">Reset</el-button>
        </el-form-item>

    </el-form>

</div>
```

App:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

    data: {

    MainForm:
    {
      dynamicValidateForm: {
        domains: [{
          key: 1,
          value: ''
        }],
      },
    },  

  rules: {
      value: [
        { required: true, message: 'Please input'},
      ],


    }
},

methods: {
 submitForm(formName) {
    this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
      if (valid) {
        alert('submit!');
      } else {
        console.log('error submit!!');
        return false;
      }
    });
  },

  addDomain() {
    this.MainForm.dynamicValidateForm.domains.push({
      key: Date.now(),
      value: ''
    });
  },

Validate(formName) {
this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
  if (valid) {
    alert('submit!');
  } else {
    console.log('error submit!!');
    return false;
  }
});
},

        }

})
```

I would like to validate all nested elements with same rule.

I also tried to do it in another way, but got another error https://jsfiddle.net/st56h3ky/
`Error: please transfer a valid prop path to form item!`

Comment: Have you checked [collections validation](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-collections-validation) of **[vuelidate](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/)**? With that it's possible to validate each item with the same rule.

Comment: @RWAM it's not native Vue Element plugins if I am right understanding, so I am afraid to get troubles with their integration Vue Element.

Comment: Did you find how to validate sub components with ElementUI?

Answer (score 2):

change the `:rules=rules` with
`:rules="rules.value"` and add change submit form button to

```
<el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('MainForm.dynamicValidateForm')">Submit</el-button>
```

like in the following code

```
<el-form :model="MainForm.dynamicValidateForm" ref="MainForm.dynamicValidateForm" label-width="120px" class="demo-dynamic">

    <el-form-item
      v-for="(domain, index) in MainForm.dynamicValidateForm.domains"
      :label="'Domain' + index"
      :key="domain.key"
      :prop="'domains.' + index + '.value'"
      :rules="rules.value"
    >
      <el-input v-model="domain.value"></el-input><el-button @click.prevent="removeDomain(domain)">Delete</el-button>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item>
      <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('MainForm.dynamicValidateForm')">Submit</el-button>
      <el-button @click="addDomain">New domain</el-button>
      <el-button @click="resetForm('MainForm.dynamicValidateForm')">Reset</el-button>
    </el-form-item>
    
</el-form>
```